# CSS Body Cursor or Dragging Cursor

Tags: html, css

I don't know why but I can't make `body{cursor:*any cursor*}`. Maybe JS Fiddle doesn't support that but it sure supports it to any element so I'm probably wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/5unnxjLa/

I don't wanna have to use a `<div>` covering the background to change it, I simply want it so that I can stop the mouse changing to the grab/text cursor when I drag the mouse on the body.

Comment: `<div>` way: https://jsfiddle.net/bL6zce79/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, either use html instead:

```
html { cursor:wait }
```

[on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2zc9ce0/)

or set `height: 100%` on both html and body:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  cursor:wait
}
```

[on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrk9rtnf/)

Answer (score 2):

The cursor property will work on the body as well, but by-default the body only wrap your elements, so it will show the cursor only within the body.
Since you have added one element in the body the defined cursor is showing at the first line.

Answer (score 1):

The `cursor` property isn't directly supported on the `body` element as it only wraps the content of your page. Instead select the `html` element and it should work as expected.

```
html{cursor:wait}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5unnxjLa/1/

Edit: If you set the width of the body to 100% and all contents within to 50%, the cursor would switch to 'waiting' only on the visible parts of the body element itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are experiencing is mainly due to the fact that the body wraps to the size of the content in it 
your CSS seems to be fine otherwise.

Try adding the following to your CSS

```
html,body{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            padding:0 0 0 0;
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
        }
```

Complete Solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            padding:0 0 0 0;
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
        }
        body{
            cursor:copy;                
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Some Content
</body>
</html>
```

Note that hyperlinks or any other block you hover over might overwrite this so if this is not the desired effect replace the relevant block with

```
body{
     cursor:copy !important;            
    }
```